# Opening a local html file in UniWebView?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, uiwebview, uniwebview

I have a class which check for internet availability, if there is not internet then it is suppose to load the file in UiWebView(I am using UniWebView).

```
    if(!isInternetAvailable())
    {
        _webView.insets = new UniWebViewEdgeInsets(0,0,0,0);
        _webView.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/File.html";
        _webView.Load();
    }
```

i cannot figure out what is wrong. I have the file stored in StreamingAssets folder. please help out. Been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: I got it working. Its the same code. my file name had an extra space.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that the way you read files from StreamingAssets is incorrect, as the method to access StreamingAssets diverts in different OS.

Please check [Unity Manual about it](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).